# Filter's using Apache poi for specific cells

Tags: apache-poi

Can anyone suggest how to apply filters in Excel using **Apachepoi** to specific columns?

I cannot Use **CellRange Address** as I am not using continuous columns.

Comment: What have you done so far? Read [ask]

Comment: I Just created an Excel Sheet with few Columns.I would like to add filter for few of the columns but not all the Columns